# In C# programs, when does a program finish executing?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it when all the threads in a process have no more instructions to execute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. When something calls [`ExitProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess) or any morally equivalent functions<sup>1</sup>, or,
2. differentiating now between background and foreground threads<sup>2</sup>, when the last foreground thread stops executing.

Threads stop executing when they return from their initial entry-point method, or, when `ExitThread` (or moral equivalents) is called on them.

---

<sup>1</sup>E.g. `Environment.Exit` or `Environment.FailFast` are two common closely equivalent managed versions.

<sup>2</sup>[Foreground and background threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/foreground-and-background-threads) are a managed code concept. Any unmanaged threads started directly through the windows API are the equivalent of foreground threads.